# python read binary file byte by byte

Tags: python

This might seem pretty stupid, but I'm a complete newbie in python.

So, I have a binary file that starts by

```
ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a
```

(as seen both through Hex Editor Neo and a java program)

yet, when I tried to read it with python by

```
with open(absolutePathInput, "rb") as f:
    while True:
        current_byte = f.read(1)
        if(not current_byte):
            break
        print(hex(current_byte[0]))
```

I get

```
ff d8 ff e0 0 10 31
```

It seems that it goes wrong whenever the first 0x00 is readen.

what am I doing wrong?
Thank u!

Comment: Are you asking about why it keeps reading past the null byte, or why it only prints `0` instead of `00`? (It *should* be printing `0x` in front of all these hex representations, and it should be printing them on separate lines; it looks like you edited the output. Please don't do that.)

Comment: What do you mean by "goes wrong"? It doesn't print what you want? It doesn't break when you want it to? What to you want to happen?

Comment: You should get a similar result with *any* byte with a leading zero.

Comment: -Since I stated before, I'm reading a **binary file** , so, no, I'm obviously not asking _why it keeps reading past the null byte_.                                       -Though this is not as obvious, since I'm reading binary data, I'm not concerned why the print() prints 0x0 instead of 0x00.                          -What I'm concerned about is **why it reads 0x31 instead of 0x4a**

Comment: My I see the output of `print(f.read(10))`

Comment: certainly, you may:  **b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10130y'**   That's my issue: dispite the fact I want to read byte by byte, I don't understand why it's reading as if it was utf-8. I guess I have to specify a certain encoding to the open(), but I dunno which one.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is you are trying to dereference current_byte as though it were an array, but it is simply a byte

```
def test_write_bin(self):  
  fname = 'test.bin'
  f = open(fname, 'wb')
  # ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a
  f.write(bytearray([255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74]))
  f.close()
  with open(fname, "rb") as f2:
    while True:
      current_byte = f2.read(1)
      if (not current_byte):
        break
      val = ord(current_byte)
      print hex(val),
  print
```

This program produces the output:

```
0xff 0xd8 0xff 0xe0 0x0 0x10 0x4a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import binascii

with open(absolutePathInput, "rb") as f:
    buff = f.read()

line = binascii.hexlify(buff)
hex_string = [line[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(line), 2)]
```

simple and violent